# DMZ Linux host in IPv6 network with changing prefix

Tags: ipv6, linux

I have the following scenario:

My home network is connected to the internet via IPv6, the router advertises the network prefix in the network so devices are auto-configured. The network prefix changes every time the internet is reconnected, so usually every 24 hours.

Inside my home network, I have a server running that has a XEN virtual server running on it. I would like this virtual server to be able to be accessible from the internet, without it being able to communicate with the local network.

At the moment I am doing this using a sit tunnel over ipv4. The XEN server has an own network bridge that only the host and the guest share, and this network bridge is configured to route the ipv4 sit traffic to the sit provider. But it would be much faster to use the native ipv6 connection instead of a tunnel. How can I realise this?

One option would be to connect the XEN guest to the local network with a bridge. Then it would be assigned an IPv6 address automatically, but would it be possible to set up firewall rules that would really separate the XEN guest from the local network? To me this sounds insecure.

Another option would be to somehow forward the Router Advertisements to the XEN guest. Then it would be assigned an IPv6 address automatically. Is it possible to forward Router Advertisements?

Another option would be to run radvd on the XEN host to send Router Advertisements to the XEN guest. How would I configure radvd to use the variable network prefix?

Comment: Wait... the ISP is _changing_ your IPv6 prefix? That's ridiculous Every _day_?! That is **absurd**.

Comment: Hm, I think it’s quite a usual thing to do for ISPs. Would be a massive privacy problem otherwise, and a lot of people would disable IPv6.

Comment: You already have privacy addresses for that. And of course changing the prefix means you break end to end connectivity, which is why you're here asking this question to begin with.

Comment: I disagree. Having one fixed IPv6 prefix per household would be equal to having one fixed IPv4 address, which would be a major privacy problem.